# what to change in this code If I want to post videos in Facebook in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, video, upload

I want to upload video on Facebook .

for this I am using my this old code , but it is not allow me to post videos in Facebook .

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)upload_image {

if (self = [super init]) {
    self.uploadImage = upload_image;
}
return self;
}
```

/**
 * this way the class is easily extensible to other file
 * types as FB allows us to upload them into the graph...
 * with little if any modification to the code 
**/

```
- (void)appendDataToBody:(NSMutableData *)body {

/**
 * Facebook Graph API only support images at the moment, surely videos must occur soon.
 **/

        NSData *picture_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage);
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\";\r\nfilename=\"media.png\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:picture_data];

}
```

Can anyone tell me what should I change here ? to post the video in Facebook?

Comment: For that you need to follow following Api Link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

Comment: @neonsamuel ... hey but this code is already included in my last project so I don't want to change it ... can you tell me what should I change in above code ? or is it not possible here ??

Comment: @SunTzu It's all given at the link...all the changes you'd need to do

Comment: Are you download the source code form that link.:-(

Comment: You can do that too...it's not much of a change...

Comment: @neonsamuel and tipycalFlow .... I am using this for my old facebook ... https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API  ... and In FBgraphFile ... this code is there , but I am not getting from this new video file :( what should I change ? because it is imp for me to stay on this old one .

Comment: @typicalFlow ... its not happening ... it is giving me error in data conversion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download the official video upload tutorial given to below link

[Official demo of the video Upload](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/VideoUploadTest.zip)

And change into the API key which is created onto

https://developers.facebook.com

Form there copy API key and put into following method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"Your Key"];
}
```

And Also change into plist file also

[image]

Thanks and Regards,

Neon Samuel