# How to upload video on facebook using facebook sdk 3.1 on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have login successfully but When I uploading video on Facebook using Facebook SDK 3.1 it can not be upload, Please Tell What can i Do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to upload a video to Facebook via Facebook graph API , check this:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

Comment: I had used that API but some time eo]rror are Failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.) and Failed with error: The request timed out.

Comment: But in my case i am not facing any type of error...

Comment: I think you miss anything while implementing it in your app...

Comment: Thanks Vishal, bt i follow same steps for given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791105/what-to-change-in-this-code-if-i-want-to-post-videos-in-facebook-in-iphone?rq=1

Comment: facebookErrDomain error 10000 you got this error because you have not authorize your app properly see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950337/getting-random-facebookerrdomain-error-10000

Comment: I give you link in answer download that project & run & check...

Comment: I could not solve the issue :Failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

Comment: See the answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328001/using-facebook-graph-api-on-ios

Comment: Vishal thanks a lot. Now i uploading video successfully

Comment: Why A Video Of our Pictures With A Background Song Rejected By Facebook within my iphone app?

Comment: Really? I don't know the reason because I don't experiment this. but how can this possible...